# Measuring directory size the way File Server Resource Manager does

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to monitor the size of various folders on a Windows 2012 Server using a ASP.net webpage. I am using the function below:

```
  private static long GetDirectorySize(String folderPath)
  {
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    return di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
  }
```

Using a particular folder as an example, it returns a value of 292.4MB but File Server Resource Manager returns 307MB. Is there a way to read the values like FSRM does?

Thanks

Comment: are there any hidden files that your Resource Manager file isn't picking up?

Comment: @SimonPrice actually the Resource Manager seems to be picking up more files than the asp.net code. To my knowledge there are no hidden files, though. I'm suspecting it's more to do with the fact that the code counts the number of bytes for each file while the FSRM checks how much space they take on the hard disk. Something to do with the way the hard disk is formatted perhaps?

Comment: the length property will be giving you the response in bytes

Comment: you'll just need to do some math on the figure to get your MB value

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. The ratio of the values is not the same for different folders. I think the number of files affects the ratio.